# Unable to compile MPI program with OpenMP with OpenMPI

Tags: fortran, mpi, openmp, openmpi

I am trying to compare solvers with one of them being parallelized in OpenMP; Solvers are all running in parallel under OpenMPI using Fixed Form Fortran 77; mpif77 does not let me link the object files with the -fopenmp switch; Make does not create the executable. I tried to compile the OpenMP source files separately with gfortran and then tried to link them with `mpif77` - does not work; When I do not use the switch it throws the common error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_GOMP_parallel", referenced from:
      _parmatdiff_ in matdiff.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [solvercomp] Error
```

1

My question is does OpenMPI support OpenMP and if yes, how do I ensure that 'make' links object files created to functions in OpenMP libraries?

Here is a copy of my makefile:

```
SOURCES = solvcomp.f matdiff.f seqjacobi.f seqconjgrad.f parsor.f
FCC = mpif77
MPIRUN = mpirun
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.f=.o)
TARGET = soln
FFLAGS = -o
CFLAGS = -c
NP = 4

all: $(TARGET) clean

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
        $(FCC) $(FFLAGS) $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)
        $(FCC) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCES)

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.dSYM
```

Comment: which version of Open MPI are you using ? can you post the error produced by `mpif77 -fopenmp` ?

Comment: Note that OpenMPI is only one of many implementations of MPI while OpenMP is a standard. So two very different things. We really need to know more details (see [ask]). Which versions do you use? What does `mpif77 -v` print? How does the last command executed by `make` look like? How does the complete output of `make` look like?

Comment: Also, what exactly happened when *"mpif77 does not let me link the object files with the -fopenmp switch"*? We need details, details, details? Any error message? Which comands did `make` execute? What was the *complete* output? Any error message? Where did you put the flag into the Makefile?

Comment: It is really best to first try to link a simple example *without* any Makefile, only with a simple.command with `mpif77 -fopenmp`. The answer to your question is likely yes, it does support. You haven't show us what *"does not work"* but OpenMPI is likely not at fault, your Makefile probably is, so **show the makefile and the complete output**. We need the details.

Comment: Here is a copy of my makefile:
SOURCES = solvcomp.f matdiff.f seqjacobi.f seqsor.f parsor.f
FCC = mpif77
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.f=.o)
TARGET = solvcomp
CFLAGS = -c -fopenmp
LFLAGS = -o

all: $(TARGET) clean

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
  $(FCC) $(LFLAGS) $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)
  $(FCC) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCES)

clean:
 rm -rf *.o *.dSYM

Comment: OpenMPI and OpenMP are the latest releases. If I omit the -fopenmp flag for linking stage it throws the above error. If I add then it gives the following error: mpif77 -c -fopenmp solvcomp.f matdiff.f seqjacobi.f seqsor.f parsor.f
mpif77 -o -fopenmp solvcomp solvcomp.o matdiff.o seqjacobi.o seqsor.o parsor.o
gfortran: error: solvcomp: No such file or directory
make: *** [solvcomp] Error 1

Comment: I did not think it was useful to post the second error message - hence did not post. The program is structured such that OpenMPI deploys the 3 solvers on 3 physical cores and then OpenMP spawns threads from the core it is running. Sorry for not being specific, I was in a rush when I posted - appreciate the help.

Comment: Please do NOT put important info in the comments. It is very hard to read it hear. [Edit] the question instead. It is useful to post all error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link command is bogus

```
mpif77 -o -fopenmp a.out foo.o
```

Try

```
LDFLAGS='-fopenmp -o'
```

As far as I am concerned, having `-o` in your `LDFLAGS` looks pretty messed up in the first place.

Comment: This solved the problem - I was having; A side question - is the order of the flags important?

Comment: Both `-o a.out -fopenmp` or `-fopenmp -o a.out` work fine, as long as `a.out` follows `-o`, that is why having `-o` in `LDFLAGS` is very unconventional since error prone.

Comment: @HimakarGanti Please do [edit] the question. It is really important. It is useless without the important information. We cannot copy it from the comments for you, because the formatting is all wrong.

Comment: I just copied the makefile content to the question - thanks for the pointer Vladimir

Comment: Ok, fine, it is the new one, so the answer does not make that much sense, but better than nothing. The one you copied into the comments would have been more natural.

Answer (score 0):

OpenMPI compiler `mpicc|mpic++|mpif70|...` is basically a program that calls a backend compiler with the appropriate flags that you need in order to include the necessary headers and link with the runtime library.

If you add the flag `-showme`, you will be able to see which compiler are you using. Although OpenMP is a standard, the compilers may have use different flags to indicate that your program must interpret OMP constructs and link with OpenMP runtime library. You can add `-showme:link` to your link command in order to see what options are being passed to the backend fortran compiler.

MPI and OpenMP are two parallel programming models commonly used together, so there shouldn't be any problem for you to do so in your programs.

https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v2.0/man1/mpicc.1.php

Comment: Well yes, but what is the OP doing wrong? How should he correct his Makefile?

Comment: the error message indicates that `-fopenmp` was used to compile the source files but was omitted when linking the object files. the real question is "what happens when linking with the `-fopenmp` flag ?". so far, all we got was "it does not work, help me !", which is pretty useless ...

Comment: OpenMPI and OpenMP are the latest releases. If I omit the -fopenmp flag for linking stage it throws the above error. If I add then it gives the following error: mpif77 -c -fopenmp solvcomp.f matdiff.f seqjacobi.f seqsor.f parsor.f
mpif77 -o -fopenmp solvcomp solvcomp.o matdiff.o seqjacobi.o seqsor.o parsor.o
gfortran: error: solvcomp: No such file or directory
make: *** [solvcomp] Error 1

Comment: I did not think it was useful to post the second error message - hence did not post. The program is structured such that OpenMPI deploys the 3 solvers on 3 physical cores and then OpenMP spawns threads from the core it is running. Sorry for not being specific, I was in a rush when I posted - appreciate the help.

Comment: Here is a copy of my makefile: SOURCES = solvcomp.f matdiff.f seqjacobi.f seqsor.f parsor.f FCC = mpif77 OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.f=.o) TARGET = solvcomp CFLAGS = -c -fopenmp LFLAGS = -o all: $(TARGET) clean $(TARGET): $(OBJECTS) $(FCC) $(LFLAGS) $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES) $(FCC) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCES) clean: rm -rf *.o *.dSYM

Comment: @HimakarGanti please update your question instead with it. Will be easier to read and more people will be able to see it.

Comment: The problem seems what @GillesGouaillardet pointed out. `CFLAGS` is omitted in the link command, so the OpenMP library is not linked, and hence the undefined symbols.

Comment: The LFLAGS is used for linker commands, not CFLAGS which is used only for compiling source files